# How to improve this for in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this `for` and I want to simplify the function `fun`

```
lst = [{"_id":"3"}, {"_id":"1"}]
key = "1"

def fun(lst, key):
    index = 0
    for item in lst:
        if key == item["_id"]:
            return index
        index += 1
    return -1

fun(lst, key)
```

> 1

Comment: This probably should be asked on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code a bit with `enumerate`:

```
def fun(lst, key):
    for index, item in enumerate(lst):
        if key == item["_id"]:
            return index
    return -1
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.